# Discrete density of $Y:= XZ+W$ with $ X \sim Bin(1,p) $ and $Z,W \sim Pois(\lambda)$.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, density-function

Let $X,Z$ and $W$ be independent random variables with $ X \sim Bin(1,p) $ and $Z,W \sim Pois(\lambda)$.

We define $$ Y:= XZ + W$$
I would like to determine the densities of $(X,Y)$ and $Y$.

I've shown that :
$$ p_{X,Y}(0,n) = P(X=0,Y=n) = $$
$$ = P(X=0,W=n) = p_X(0)*p_W(n)= $$
$$=(1-p)\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!} $$
by taking into account the independence assumption.

Then I've shown that :

$$ p_{X,Y}(1,n)=P(X=1,Y=n)=P(X=1,Z+W=n)=p_X(1)*p_{Z+W}(n)=$$

$$=p\frac{e^{-2\lambda}(2\lambda)^n}{n!}$$

Now It remains to compute the density for $ Y=XZ+W$. 
So 
$$ p_Y(n)=P(XZ+W=n) $$
If $X=0$ we have that $W=n$ and when $X=1$ we get $Z+W=n$.

Can the density  $p_Y(n)$ be written directly in terms of the densities previously defined? I'm not sure how to procede from here but I believe that $ p_Y(n) $ can be written as the sum of $p_{X,Y}(1,n)$ and $p_{X,Y}(0,n)$, but I'm not so sure.

Any support for this question would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you've computed the joint correctly, and to get the marginal $p_Y(n)$ you simply sum $p_{X,Y}(x,n)$ over $x$, as you say.

Comment: Thanks @JimFerry for the answer, but i don't understand with surely why I have to sum $p_{X,Y}(x,n)$ over $x$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is simply what a Marginal Probability Distribution is.  Cf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution